# Drupal page doesn't scroll to hash div in URL if comments are enabled

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-comments

I'm having a peculiar problem with comments in Drupal. If I enable writing comments in a node, and I put a hash tag in the url (for example, node/123#footer), it will load for a split second at the correct div and jump right back to the top. This doesn't happen on any other page of the site where there are no comments. It also doesn't happen if I disable comments or set comments to read-only for the node. It's not Javascript and it's not my theme because the same thing happens if I disable JS in my browser (tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Opera) and use Garland. I've also changed the node's comment settings to every combination I could think of.

I want to use this because I have a lot of links that jump directly to a comment (each comment has id="comment-cid") but it's pretty useless right now!

Any idea where to look? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check thr source to see if there are any actual anchors available ?
If you have commentes over multiple pages(I mean 30 comments per page), then node/123#comment-3232 won't work if the comment-3232 is in ?page=1 or 2,3,etc.

Comment: Yeah I did! It actually does go to the correct div for a split second but when the page is done loading, it jumps to the top of the page!